# Check if call is made using TOR client

Tags: php, dns, tor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Block TOR Servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294244/block-tor-servers)

I would like to know if it is possible to see if a call to my PHP page is done by a TOR client (meaning the call comes in over the TOR project network). 
Today I call a bunch of IP adresses gotten from https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py, but it would be more fun if I can spoof the data send back to the thieves leaching my API.

I can't think of anyway to find out, is it possible? How?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780038/is-it-possible-to-block-tor-users, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294244/block-tor-servers

Comment: Thnx... weirdly enough I didn't find them. I'll vote close it with regards to your second link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7214-PHP-Check-if-an-IP-is-TOR-network-exit-address.html) might be just want you need  .. it check for `ip-port.exitlist.torproject.org` in DNS information and  determine if an user is accessing a site using the Tor network.

Example

```
$tor = Tor::getInstance(); 

// check current users ip and 
// return true or false 
var_dump($tor->isTorActive()); 

// check ip of another user 
var_dump($tor->setTarget('1.2.3.4')->isTorActive());
```

[See Full Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7214-PHP-Check-if-an-IP-is-TOR-network-exit-address.html)

Comment: @Paul Peelen you are welcome ....

Comment: I wrote a super simple REST API to determine whether a request was made from TOR network or not. It works just like The Class. [https://github.com/RD17/DeTor](https://github.com/RD17/DeTor)

Comment: This sollution does not work anymore, check out the one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780038/is-it-possible-to-block-tor-users/61623796#61623796